# Evaluating a function that is defined by Minimize

Tags: evaluation

I want to find a global minimum of a function and plot the result for different parameters.

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]]
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Clear[Derivative]
$Assumptions = m \[Element] Integers;
nini[w_, k_, \[Nu]_] := -( 2/3) ((1 - \[Nu]) (1 - k) + k) ((w^4/40) k^2  + 2/3)^-1 // FullSimplify
n0 = nini[\[Omega], 2 \[Pi]/L, \[Nu]];
k[x_, L_, m_] := (2 \[Pi])/L + \[Rho] A Sin[(2 \[Pi])/L m x]
n[x_, L_, m_] := nini[\[Omega], 2 \[Pi]/L, \[Nu]] + \[Rho] B Sin[(2 \[Pi])/L m x] + \[Rho]^2 c
eqs[L_, \[Omega]_, t_, \[Nu]_, m_] := Normal[Series[240 \[Nu] k[x, L, m] + 9 \[Omega]^4 k[x, L, m]^2 n[x, L, m] + 40 (6 n[x, L,m] + (-1 + \[Nu]) (-6 + t  \[Omega]^2 D[n[x, L, m], {x, 2}])) == 0, {\[Rho],0,1}]] /. \[Rho] -> 1 // FullSimplify
B = B /. Solve[eqs[L, \[Omega], t, \[Nu], m] /. c -> 0 , {B}][[1]] // FullSimplify
c = 0;
n[x, L, m, \[Nu]]
n[x, 1, 1, 1]
```

The input n[x, L, m, [Nu]] return the next expression

```
(20 L (L (-1+\[Nu])-2 \[Pi] \[Nu]))/(20 L^2+3 \[Pi]^2 \[Omega]^4)+(60 A L^2 \[Rho] (-20 L^2 \[Nu]+3 \[Pi] (L-L \[Nu]+\[Pi] \[Nu]) \[Omega]^4) Sin[(2 m \[Pi] x)/L])/((20 L^2+3 \[Pi]^2 \[Omega]^4) (60 L^2+\[Pi]^2 \[Omega]^2 (-40 m^2 t (-1+\[Nu])+9 \[Omega]^2)))
```

But when I insert numbers for $L$ for example, $L^2$ is not evaluated:

```
n[x, 1, 1, 1]
```

returns

```
-((40 \[Pi])/(20+3 \[Pi]^2 \[Omega]^4))+(60 A L^2 \[Rho] (-20 L^2 \[Nu]+3 \[Pi] (L-L \[Nu]+\[Pi] \[Nu]) \[Omega]^4) Sin[2 \[Pi] x])/((20 L^2+3 \[Pi]^2 \[Omega]^4) (60 L^2+\[Pi]^2 \[Omega]^2 (-40 m^2 t (-1+\[Nu])+9 \[Omega]^2)))
```

Comment: You might want to post the problem you're trying to solve, as your code will probably need a lot of improvement. A single evaluation of the objective in NMinimize, for instance `H[100, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1]` takes far too long to return. Not only that, the result still contains symbols, so the NMinimize will not work.

Comment: When I run the first block of code, `Solve` produces a warning message and a conditional answer.  You should investigate this.  Also, what is the purpose of `Clear[Derivative]`?